# Outputting XML data to HTML by use of JS

Tags: javascript, xml

**Problem:**

Trying to print one question and 4 answers at a time from an XML file.

**JS code:**

```
var xmlDoc, quest, ans, i, n;

xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("questions.xml");
quest = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('main');

document.write("<table border='1'>");

for (i = 0; i < quest.length; i+=1)
{
    document.write("<tr><td>");
    document.write( quest[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue );
    document.write("</td></tr>");

    for(n = 0; n < 4; n++) 
    {
        document.write("<tr><td>");
        document.write( quest[i].childNodes[n].nodeValue );
        document.write("</td></tr>");
    }
}

document.write("</table>");
```

**Desired output:**

Each question comes with four answers below it. Right now only the questions are being printed correctly.

The structure for the XML file is:

```
<main>
    <instruction></instruction>
    <solution></solution>
    <solution></solution>
    <solution></solution>
    <solution></solution>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
var xmlDoc, quest, ans, i, n;

xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("questions.xml");
quest = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('main');

document.write("<table border='1'>");

for (i = 0; i < quest.length; i+=1)
{
    document.write("<tr><td>");
    document.write( quest[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue );
    document.write("</td></tr>");

    for(n = 1; n < 5; n++) // m = 1 because [0] is the title.
    {
        document.write("<tr><td>");
        document.write( quest[i].childNodes[n].nodeValue );
        document.write("</td></tr>");
    }
}

document.write("</table>");
```

Comment: How can I add this code to a specific part of a HTML page? When I use it now, the page gets replaced by this code.

Comment: Yeah obviously. You need to store this data in variables and then print them at required positions.